# Windows как сделать fdopen на socket ?

Tags: windows, c, сокет

Получаю сокет fd = accept(), пытаюсь (программа из Unix'a) сделать fdopen(). Валится (после минуты раздумий это уже кажется естественным (т.к. fd == 316)).

Вопрос : fdopen() на socket в Windows - **это возможно ???**

**UPD 1**

Пока не получается, но найденная в http://msdn.microsoft.com/ функция _open_osfhandle() внушает надежду ...

Comment: Если совсем не получается, пиши в буфер с помощью sprintf, а потом write (или что там еще в виндах) в сокет. Или наоборот - читай в буфер, потом разбирай sscanf.

Comment: Да, покручу еще вечерком, не получится, кусочек stdio придется на send()/recv() делать.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще это понадобилось? Ведь есть же уже сокет, куда вам ещё один хэндл для него? По сути разницы то нет что там читать из сокета, что эдак.

Comment: В идеале (как в unix) ХОЧУ fgets(), fprintf() и т.п. 

Если не получится, то "спрятать" буферизацию. Сейчас уже почти уверен, что напрямую первое не получится (с сокетом (или полученным от него дескриптором (_open_osfhandle()))в виндах похоже read()/write() не заработают).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, (б...) да **fdopen( _open_osfhandle(fd,_O_ACCMODE|_O_APPEND), ... )** заработал.

(наверняка Билли подкинет еще какие-нибудь подлянки)

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define socket(x,y,z) WSASocket (x,y,z,NULL,0,0)
#endif
```

Теперь самый интересный вопрос к сообществу ***Почему это так ???***

Т.е.  почему в библиотеках MS есть socket() и WSASocket(), **которые ведут себя по разному ???**

Comment: Вот поэтому я предпочитаю писать под линь.

Comment: Я тоже. Винду, как обычно, в голове держит заказчик. Приходится по ходу и самому прикидывать, что легко перенесется, а что нет.